# Is there an event in Delphi that fires when ActiveControl changes?

Tags: delphi, controls

I would like to run a small routine whenever the `ActiveControl` changes. How can I do this? I thought about having a timer that checks the active control at certain intervals, and fires my routine when it changes, but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[TScreen.OnActiveControlChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.OnActiveControlChange)